# My two word app name is being displayed as one word

Tags: ios

I have my app name set to 'Random Game' but for some reason on the launch screen it is displaying as 'RandomGame'. I know it's kind of small but it's really bugging me. This is my Xcode project:[image]

And this is how it's coming out:
[image]

Comment: how about "Random  Game", adding 2 space instead of 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like two words to me, just the text has been squashed a bit because your name is long.  See what it looks like if you change it to "Rand Game".

Comment: Do you suggest a name like it but just shorter?

Comment: This sounds logical - that they'd squash the space a little instead of truncating the text.
I think that @Ewan is suggesting to try "Rand Game" to see if the space becomes larger and therefore prove the theory - rather than switching the name to "Rand Game" permanently.

Comment: It is being squashed. The weird part is, though, when I go onto siri suggestions it shows the name fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check you Info.plist. Be sure that your bundle display name is set to "Random Game".

Comment: It is I removed the Bundle name and made a new one called Random Game

Answer (score 0):

Open launchscreen.storyboard and make the changes.